# Extract sum of 9 pixels into point feature class

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have a task to create a grid (point feature class)(using Create Fishnet) in the extent of population raster (value of 1px represents number of people living in that area)  and then extract values of the raster into this grid. However, in each point of the grid, I don´t want only the value of the pixel right below the grid point, but sum of values of this point and 8 neighboring pixels, so sum of 9 pixels. I tried using **Extract Values to Points**, but it only allows to extract the 1 value of the pixel below the point. The idea is that in the end, summing up these extracted values from the points should be equal to summing up values of all pixels of the underlying raster. So any idea, how should I go about this? Is this possible in arcpy?

[image]

[The point feature represented by black dot shoud contain attribute value of sum of raster pixel values of 9 neighboring pixels arround and including the pixel under the point (9 pixels that should be summed up are represented by distinct colors]

Comment: Assuming you have spatial analyst extension available use Aggregate http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000034000000 with a factor of 3 and type of SUM then Raster to Point.

Comment: Polygon neighbors will do. Transfer polygon attributes into it and summarise. Unless you are talking about focal statistics

Answer (score 3):

The "Focal Statistics" tool can be set up to Sum a rectangular window of 3 x 3 cells in a moving window. This creates a new raster layer from which you can extract your values to your points.

The ArcPy syntax for this is at:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm